# Diferencia entre ActionPerformed y MouseClicked Java

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a ver el tema de interfaz gráfica en java, y me fijo que si se le asigna un evento a un *JButton* ej: *MouseClicked* es un método diferente de *ActionPerformed*, Cual es la diferencia entre este y cualquier otro evento que se le asigne?, Que sucede en caso de no asignar ningún evento a el botón?.

Answer (score 3):

Primero, es importante ser preciso para evitar confusiones. No se "asigna un evento" a un componente, se le asigna un *listener* que dicho componente acepte. El *listener* tendrá definidos varios métodos que el componente invocará cuando necesite notificar un evento.

`mouseClicked()` es un método de `MouseListener`, `actionPerformed()` es un método de `ActionListener`. Las dos clases tienen funciones distintas; `MouseListener` trata con eventos a bajo nivel (lo que se hace con el ratón), los eventos de `ActionListener` son más a alto nivel. Por ejemplo, al hacer click en un botón, se invocará el método `mouseClicked` de los `MouseListener` asociados, y el método `actionPerformed()` de los `ActionListener`. Pero si navegas con el tabulador y en el botón pulsas Intro, no llamará a `mouseClicked()` pero sí a `actionPerformed()`.

¿Qué pasa si un componente no tiene *listeners* asignados? Pues no llamará a ningún método cuando detecte el evento, no se ejecutará ninguna lógica.

Answer (score 0):

ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) es un evento de ActionListener. ActionListener se usa para detectar y manejar eventos, los cuales tienen lugar cuando se produce una acción sobre un elemento del programa.

En otras palabras al hablar de ActionPerformed nos referimos al evento que se produce al hacer click en un componente o al pulsar Enter (teniendo el foco en el componente). Mientras que un MouseClicked, como su nombre lo indica, es más específico al ser un evento que entra en acción (SOLAMENTE) cuando se da clic sobre un elemento.

Por otro lado, si no agregas ningún evento al componente, este último no realizará ninguna acción